# cts:search() in MarkLogic is returning an empty sequence

Tags: marklogic

I am using MarkLogic to query over a relative large xml dataset. Now I am using two sets of query like these:

> 1. xdmp:estimate(cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:and-query(($query, $text-query, $sent-query))))
> 2. xdmp:estimate(cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:and-not-query(cts:and-query(($query, $text-query)), $sent-query)))

where,
**$text-query := cts:word-query("coke")**

**$sent-query := cts:and-query((cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("score_id"),">=",$lowValue),
              cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("score_id"),"<",$hiValue)))**

**$query := cts:word-query("diet coke")**

**$lowValue := 13264683002210000000;**

**$hiValue := 13264683002211000000;**

For both the sets(query no. 1 and 2), I am getting some **counts**, but when I am removing the `xdmp:estimate` part, the `cts:search()` for **query 1.** is returning the xmls, where as for the query no. 2, I am getting an empty sequence.

My question is that, if `cts:search` is not returning any xmls, then how can the `xdmp:estimate` is counting the nodes for the **query no. 2** ??

Is the `cts:and-not-query` is not comfortable with the `cts:element-range-query`, although ???

N.B. I am getting some counts with `xdmp:estimate` with out any errors.
      Range index is created over the field "**score_id**".

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `unfiltered` option to the `cts:search` calls.

http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/apidoc/SearchBuiltins.xml&category=SearchBuiltins&function=cts:search

Chances are that `cts:search` is returning empty because fragments match the indexes but are filtered out as false positives. The unfiltered results should help you decide if that is correct, or might be evidence of a bug.

Answer (score 2):

In particular, the "estimate" will use indexes only. If you do not have "fast phrase" indexes it can't tell directly from the indexes if the phrase "diet coke" is in the document - it will instead use the indexes in the "index resolution" phase of a query to find all documents with both "diet" and "coke." Later for the real query it will "filter" these candidate documents to see if the two words are actually right next to each other.

See the MarkLogic search developers guide, with particular attention to "index resolution" and "filtering."

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably comes from `xdmp:estimate` as it shows the number of fragments that potentially can have hits (false positive too), not only does that actually have.

Try using `fn:count` instead of `xdmp:estimate` as it will produce the correct result each time,the only problem is it is slower than `xdmp:estimate`

For more information:
[MarkLogic Server: Search Developer's Guide Chapter 11](http://developer.marklogic.com/pubs/5.0/books/search-dev-guide.pdf)